# Put in a queue functions with different arguments C++11

Tags: c++11, queue, bind, func

I am working in C++11. I try to create a queue that takes variadic arguments.
The first approach that I tried is the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
std::queue<std::function<void()>> funcs;
class ThePool
{
    public:
    template<class... Args>
    void Add_Job(function<void( Args&& ... arg)> New_Job)
    {

    }
   template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
   void QueueFunction(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
   {
         std::function<void()> func = std::bind(std::forward<_Callable 
         (__f), std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
        funcs.push(func);
    }
    void print(int i )
    {
       cout << "Hello Word"<< i <<endl;
   }

 };
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ThePool a;
    a.QueueFunction(&ThePool::print,a, 5);
    std::function<void()> func = funcs.back();
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

But I would like to pass arguments in  the functions that are bind using the placeholders. For example I like to pass more that one type of functions.
For example I would like to pass a void function with one argument or two arguments and e.t.c
How I should modify the QueueFunction method and the funcs queue in order to support something like this?
For example use bind like this
`std::bind(&QueueFunction ::print, &a, std::placeholders::_1);`
but in more generic format

Best regards
George

Comment: Let's assume it is doable, but how would you use it? How would you determine which kind of function did you take out of pool and what to pass to it? Or you simply need more pools, which would solve your problem. Also, I recommend using lambdas, so no bind nor placeholders are needed.

Comment: Thank you for  the reply. I have in my mind is to create a thread pool that will be used as a library.

Comment: Yes, but given that you have a function pool, that you feed to workers threads, how do worker thread recognize what function signature it takes out of pool and which arguments should it pass into it?

Comment: Following up my previous commend how I can use lamdas instead of bind in this case?

Comment: The point is that a group of threads that use the thread poll must have the same signature. You should define an other working pool that is used by different workers for tasks with different signatures

Comment: Lambda is directly convertible to std::function, thus you can do `funcs.push([&a]{a.print(5);});` to "bind" into call to `ThePool::print` with a and 5

Comment: This is clear to me. But this that I confused me is how to use a lamda expression inside the function QueueFunction instead of bind in order to make this in a generic way.  This usefull for switch between a old one compiler that does not support C++11 or 14 and a new one changing only one function